# How can I use azure release pipeline variables using powershell?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I have tried below approaches but not working.

```
$env:variableName, $(variableName), ${env:variableName}
```

Comment: It should works in the first method you tried, can you share exactly what you tried? can you share the logs?

Comment: first and last one should work, unless they are secret

Comment: echo "hint is $env:variableName"
and it gives: hint is 
(Not able to read the variable.)

Comment: For future reference, it is pretty specific in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came to know very strange behaviour that the variable must be in all uppercase then only I am able to get the value on Linux.

Comment: Tried echo "hint is $env:VARIABLENAME" and it worked.